# Problem when uploading file from React to Laravel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to upload a file from reactjs project to Laravel backend.

In react I have it set up like this (components are from reactstrap):

```
<FormGroup>
  <Label for="invoice">
    <IntlMessages id="words.invoice" />
  </Label>
  <Input
    type="file"
    name="invoice"
    onChange={this.handleInvoiceChange}
  />
</FormGroup>;
```

and in handleInvoiceChange I set the file to state

```
handleInvoiceChange = e => {
  this.setState({
    formData: {
      ...this.state.formData,
      invoice: e.target.files[0]
    }
  });
};
```

and sending form to server

```
submitForm = () => {
  const formData = { ...this.state.formData };
  console.log("send data", formData);
  axios.post(`items/edit/${this.itemId}`, formData).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
};
```

When sending form to server, I check the data in console:
[image]

In laravel, I try to dump file with

```
$invoice = $request->file('invoice');

dd($invoice);
```

But this is always empty.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that's because that `FormData` in the code is not really [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), it's just `JSON` data.

I would initial a FormData object and append the data.

```
submitForm = () => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('invoice', this.state.formData.invoice);
  ...  //  append more data

  axios.post(`items/edit/${this.itemId}`, formData).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
};
```

If it's not this reason, please check the whole `$request` data in `laravel` to see
what it really received.